# How does one use cleveref in an arxiv submission?

Tags: cleveref, arxiv

`cleveref` (in particular `\cref` and `\Cref`) does not seem to work on Arxiv, resulting in "**??**" instead of the correct reference such as "Section 2" or "Theorem 3". Is there a workaround?

Note that arxiv does compile twice (of course) and in general the compilation works fine for complex documents.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

a

\section{Test section}
\label{test}

\cref{test}
\end{document}
```

Which results in this when compiled on arxiv, with "??" instead of "Section 1".
[image: PDF output]

Here is the log provided by arxiv:

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]:  is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'cleveref-test.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1397210/ && latex 'cleveref-test.tex' &1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cleveref-test.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
No file cleveref-test.aux.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `test' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.

[1] (./cleveref-test.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `cleveref-test.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

)
Output written on cleveref-test.dvi (1 page, 2372 bytes).
Transcript written on cleveref-test.log.

[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1397210/ && latex 'cleveref-test.tex' &1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cleveref-test.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(./cleveref-test.aux) (/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./cleveref-test.out) (./cleveref-test.out)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `test' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.

[1] (./cleveref-test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

)
Output written on cleveref-test.dvi (1 page, 2460 bytes).
Transcript written on cleveref-test.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'cleveref-test.out' (1446737883 >= 1446737882)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'cleveref-test.aux' (1446737883 >= 1446737882)
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'cleveref-test.dvi'
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1397210/ && dvips -R2 -z 'cleveref-test.dvi' -o )" 2>&1
[verbose]: dvi(h)ps said ...
This is dvips(k) 5.991 Copyright 2011 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2015.11.05:1538' -> cleveref-test.ps



.


[1]

.
[verbose]: Backing up 'cleveref-test.ps'. Going to change %%Title line.
[verbose]: %%Title: line found and changed.
[verbose]: Title change completed.
[verbose]: Backing up 'cleveref-test.ps'. Going to add a name/date stamp to it.
[verbose]: OK, inserting the stamp
[verbose]: Stamping completed.
[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: Processing DVI
[verbose]: Gzipping and moving cleveref-test.dvi
[verbose]: Gzipping ...1397210/cleveref-test.dvi
[verbose]: Processing postscript
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for cleveref-test.dvi
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for cleveref-test.dvi.gz
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for cleveref-test.ps
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for cleveref-test.tex
[verbose]: Gzipping ...1397210/cleveref-test.ps
[verbose]: Moving .../1397210/cleveref-test.dvi.gz => .../1397210/tex_cache/1397210.dvi.gz

[verbose]: Moving .../1397210/cleveref-test.ps.gz => .../1397210/tex_cache/1397210.ps.gz

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you compile the Tex file twice? What does the log file say? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: Is the compilation not done by `arxiv`?

Comment: It's arxiv which compiles it, and yes the system is quite smart and does compile it twice. I'll update the question with the log provided by arxiv.

Comment: The log file shows that `hyperref` is being loaded *after* `cleveref`; your MWE, in contrast, doesn't feature mention `hyperref` to begin with. Is the MWE you've posted identical to the one you're compiling on arxiv's server?

Comment: Yes, the MWE is the exact contents of the (single) file that I uploaded to arxiv to test this. But thanks for the clue! It turns out arxiv automatically adds hyperref, but that can be disabled as per https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes . With that I got cleveref to work.

Comment: I suspect the problem arose because `hyperref` was being loaded (by the arxiv server) *automatically but after `cleveref`*. As an alternative to disabling `hyperref` outright, you may want to find out if you have better luck if the `hyperref` package is loaded explicitly in the preamble, *before* `cleveref` is loaded. (`cleveref` must be loaded after `hyperref`.)

Comment: @Mico, that works for me.  You should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

(Followed up on a suggestion to make an earlier comment into an answer.)

According to the log file you've posted, the `hyperref` package is being loaded after the `cleveref` package. However, `cleveref` is one of the packages that should be loaded after `hyperref`. This problem appears to arise because the arxiv server automatically loads `hyperref` if it hasn't been loaded explicitly.

As an alternative to disabling `hyperref` outright, you may try loading the `hyperref` package *before* `cleveref` is loaded.